# Does this SQL code run procedurally?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to generate a batch of separate reports and rename them. Some of the reports are being given a name of the following report, other reports are being generated twice.

Will this section of SQL code run line by line like it would in a procedural language?

```
        BEGIN
            --Execute the report
            EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData=  'eca9df5f-270b-4460-a912-360cfd73a476';
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
            -- Update processed_reports table once SSRS has executed
            UPDATE [ARCHIVER].[dbo].[test_processed_reports] 
            SET [test_processed_reports].[report_status] = 'processed', [test_processed_reports].[time_stamp] = GETDATE()
            WHERE batch_serial_no = @batch_counter 
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';
            -- Rename reports
            EXEC [dbo].[sp_ReplaceFileOrDirNames] @batch_counter,'C:\Reports' ,'Main_Report.pdf';
            WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';           
        END
```

For example will it: Execute the ReportServer job, Wait for 10secs, Update the table of processed reports, wait for 2secs, then rename the report and then wait for 2secs.

Comment: Have you even tried?

Comment: It does execute the statements 1 by 1, but when you start the `UPDATE` how can you know for sure that the Report is done executing? Is it `always` executed under 10 seconds, assuming the added event in `dbo.Event` is executed immediately?

Comment: @NickyvV Thanks for clarifying the execution order for me. With the script just doing an update, through trial and error, the ten second delay seemed to be sufficient. Could it be that the addition of the extra renaming execution requires a bigger delay. I'm testing it at the moment by changing the two second delays to five seconds. Is there any way to measure how long report generation takes? I'm new to SQL and Reporting Services.

Comment: @krustie92 these are not the best solutions I'm afraid. What are you trying to achieve here? Never used Integration Services? For the Report execution you could check the `dbo.Event` table for the `@EventData` to see if the execution is completed.

Comment: @NickyvV I guessed I probably wasn't doing it in the best way. I'm trying to generate and rename reports individualized based on their batch serial no in SS2008R2 Standard. So I've had to make do without data driven subscriptions. Each report should be generated on an end of batch message. So I've a trigger to add batch serial no to a table of unprocessed reports. Then a scheduled procedure to generate and rename the reports in the table of unprocessed reports. It loops through the above code. I've never used Integration Services

Answer (score -1):

BEGIN
            declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

```
        set @SQL ='
        EXEC <SPNAME>  
        WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:10''';                        
        exec (@SQL) 

       set @SQL ='
             UPDATE [ARCHIVER].[dbo].[test_processed_reports] 
        SET [test_processed_reports].[report_status] = ''processed'', [test_processed_reports].[time_stamp] = GETDATE()
        WHERE batch_serial_no = @batch_counter 
        WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:02''';                        
        exec (@SQL)   


      set @SQL ='
        EXEC <SPNAME> 
        WAITFOR DELAY ''00:00:2''';                        
        exec (@chvSQL)
```